# Switch/Case for multiple enum values

Tags: c++, enums

I have got two values, each one from a different enum. I want to check for a allowed combination of these two and perform a default action if none is found. Can I somehow do a switch/case on both of these values? I would like to avoid multiple if/else statements, or enums that follow a bit-mask pattern, simply because I think they are not as pretty in code as a switch/case.

For the people knowing Python, I basically want a solution for this Python code in C++:

```
val1 = "a"
val2 = 2
actions = {
    ("a", 1): func1,
    ("b" ,1): func2,
    ("a" ,2): func3,
    ("b" ,2): func4
}
action = actions.get((val1, val2), default_func)()
action()
```

Comment: It sound like you might want a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`

Comment: So i pretty much do the same thing as in python, just with a map of a pair and a function pointer?

Comment: Yep.  You could also use a `std::function` so you can mix function pointers and lambdas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::map` with `std::pair` keys and `std::function` values comes to mind.

More precisely, you can map function objects to specific pairs of enum objects. Here is an example:

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

enum class Enum1
{
    a, b, c
};

enum class Enum2
{
    one, two, three
};

int main()
{
    auto const func1 = [] { std::cout << "func1\n"; };
    auto const func2 = [] { std::cout << "func2\n"; };
    auto const func3 = [] { std::cout << "func3\n"; };
    auto const func4 = [] { std::cout << "func4\n"; };
    auto const default_func = [] { std::cout << "default\n"; };

    std::map<std::pair<Enum1, Enum2>, std::function<void()>> const actions =
    {
        {{ Enum1::a, Enum2::one }, func1 },
        {{ Enum1::b, Enum2::one }, func2 },
        {{ Enum1::a, Enum2::two }, func3 },
        {{ Enum1::b, Enum2::two }, func4 }
    };

    auto const val1 = Enum1::a;
    auto const val2 = Enum2::two;

    auto const action_iter = actions.find({ val1, val2 });
    auto const action = action_iter != actions.end() ? action_iter->second : default_func;
    action();
}
```

Comment: I would use `std::array<std::array<std::function<void()>,3>, 3>` instead of `std::map<std::pair<Enum1, Enum2>, std::function<void()>>`.

Answer (score 4):

> Can i somehow do a switch/case on both of these values?

No, you can't. `switch` works only with one value. If you can't transform the two values into one integral value, you'll have to use other methods. Here are a couple of methods that I could think of.

1. You could use a cascading `if-else` statements.

   ```
   if ( val1 == "a" && val2 == 1 )
   {
      func1();
   }
   else if ( val1 == "b" && val2 == 1 )
   {
      func2();
   }
   else if ( val1 == "a" && val2 == 2 )
   {
      func3();
   }
   else if ( val1 == "b" && val2 == 2 )
   {
      func4();
   }
   ```
2. You could also use a `map`.

   ```
   using map_type = std::map<std::pair<decltype(val1), decltype(val2)>, decltype(func1)>;
   map_type functions = {{ {"a", 1}, func1}, { {"a", 1}, func1}, { {"a", 1}, func1}, { {"a", 1}, func1}};

   auto iter = functions.find(std::make_pair(val1, val2));
   if ( iter != functions.end() )
   {
      iter->second();
   }
   ```